# CSS is getting apply despite of comments??

Tags: php, html, css, comments

I have seen Commented CSS in my PHP page enclosed within `<!-- -->`

like

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body { }
...

-->
</style>
```

when I was optimizing my code then I deleted those commented CSS code from my page,

but after deleting, layout of that page has been disturbed.

when I again paste those commented CSS , it was working fine??

please tell me the reason and how does it possible that CSS is applying despite of comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're using the wrong comments syntax, you ***should*** be using: `/* ... */` to comment out CSS, the `<!-- ... -->` is html comment syntax; and once you're inside of the `style` element html is itself invalid and can, therefore, be handled by the browser as it sees fit.

Therefore you may want to try:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*
body { }
...

*/
</style>
```

It's worth noting that, like html, there is no single-line comment syntax, which in JavaScript for example would be anything following `//`.

*Some* further information: [CSS - smarter code comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712404/css-smarter-code-comments/3712420#3712420)

Answer (score 2):

HTML comments don't apply to CSS. You need to use CSS-style comments:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

/* This is a comment. The following rule will be applied. */
body { }

/* This rule has been commented out
h1 { }
*/
-->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Those (`<!-- xx -->`) are HTML comments, which does NOT affect CSS.

To comment out CSS, use `/* xx */`